# How to modify Podfile in an EXPO Managed project - React native

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I has implemented an App that uses rnfirebase for analytics, but with the new App Tracking Transparency of Apple I have to request permission to user for tracking it. Really I use Analytic to improve my app and don't need the IDFA, then is annoying to me to request a permission that at the end of the day I don't use it.

My question: How to change podfilde in an EXPO managed workflow to disabled IDFA as firebase recommend for cases as mine. See this link https://rnfirebase.io/analytics/usage#disable-ad-id-usage-on-ios

I couldn't find nothing on internet of how to do that and EXPO docs is understandably (at least for me in this specific regard). https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/#modifying-the-ios-podfile

Any help would be appreciated a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was given by @giautm. Thank you for your time!

An example was published in: https://gist.github.com/giautm/402e1732c89548281d6605ef77289476

Then all you need is to add the path in your app.json, and job will be made.

Happy coding!

Comment: We are in the same boat. Can you post more details like what the path is you mentioned pointed to? Is the link you posted a config plugin? Etc.... Need more detail to get this done.

Comment: 1. Download the file from the link above and copy it in a folder of your project. 2. In the app.json of your project create a new key (if you don't have it already) named plugins and after that refer the url of the file from step 1. You should have something like that in your app.json in case you have copied the file in the root project -> "plugins": ["./rnf-disable-ad-id-support.plugin.js"]. And that is all. Expo will be the rest. Cheers.

Comment: this didn't work for me on a managed expo project using a custom dev client, I get the error `error: Multiple commands produce...`